# Bootstrap Tooltip on Navbar submenu not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use tooltip on a navbar;
It works great if its implemented on a menu item which has no sub-menu items, but if i try to use it on a sub-menu item, it wont work.

My Navbar code:

```
<!-- ============ START NAVBAR =========== -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a href="#/" class="pull-left"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <!-- Home Menu -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Home </b><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
            <li><a href="documents/Newsletters/Open House Newsletter Summer 2016.pdf" target="_blank">Latest News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#events">Coming Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#involved">Get Involved</a></li>
            <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ceo">CEO Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bibleRead">Bible Reading</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pray">Pray For Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

         <!-- About Us Menu -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>About Us </b><b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu2">
             <li>
               <a href="">Who We Are <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="#origins">Our Origins</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#ourhistory">Our History</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#what">What We Do</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#why">Why We Do It</a></li>
                 <li><a href="documents/Strategic Plan-promotional.pdf" target="_blank">Strategic Plan</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
               <a href="">Our People <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="#board">Our Board</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#volunteers">Volunteers</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#supporters">Supporters</a></li>
                 <!--<li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>-->
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
             <li><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
             <li><a href="#reports">Annual Reports</a></li>
             <li><a href="#newsletter">News Letters</a></li>
             <li><a href="#jobs">Job Vacancies</a></li>
             <li><a href="#policies">Policies</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>

        <!-- Programs Menu -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Programs </b><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu3">
            <li>
              <a href="">Children and Youth <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#mothers">Play Group</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#child">Children and Youth</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="#boys">Boys 2 Men</a></li>
                <li><a href="#girls">Fun 4 Girls</a></li>
                <li><a href="#teens">Drop In Cafe</a></li>
                <li><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#youth" data-original-title="Youth Workshop Mentoring Program">YWMP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#backyard">Backyard Sports</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="">Adults <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#adult">Adult Workshops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bibleFellow">Bible Fellowship</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clubwork">Clubwork</a></li>
                <li><a href="#arts">Arts and Crafts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#mens">Mens Support Group</a></li>
                <li><a href="#individual">Individual Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#meal">Community Meal</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

         <!-- Testimonials Menu -->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Testimonials </b><span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#participants">Participants</a></li>
            <li><a href="#caregive">Care Givers</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="#sponsors">Our Sponsors</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#links" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!"><b>Useful links </b></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><b>Contact Us </b></a></li>
        <li><a href="#donations" id="donationBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-25px; !important; color: #ffffff;"><b> Donations </b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- ============ END NAVBAR =========== -->
```

Within this Navbar code, it will work on "Useful Links" (which is a main menu item)

```
<li><a href="#links" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!"><b>Useful links </b></a></li>
```

But if I try to use it on "YWMP" which is a submenu, it wont;

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Programs </b><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu3">
            <li>
              <a href="">Children and Youth <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#mothers">Play Group</a></li>
                <li><a href="#boys">Boys 2 Men</a></li>
                <li><a href="#girls">Fun 4 Girls</a></li>
                <li><a href="#teens">Drop In Cafe</a></li>
                <li><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#youth" data-original-title="Youth Workshop Mentoring Program">YWMP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#backyard">Backyard Sports</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

Oh, and here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your tooltip to display, you need to have a `title` attribute. Replace

```
<a ... data-original-title="Youth Workshop Mentoring Program">YWMP</a>
```

with

```
<a ... title="Youth Workshop Mentoring Program">YWMP</a>
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thanks... solved my issue.

Rookie mistake - i was using this jsfiddle as an original example for the YWMP menu item, before switching to the W3Schools example for the 'Useful Links' menu item.
(I'm guessing the jsfiddle was using some custom css & jquery which wasn't included)
http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vSTLU/2/